# Kivy how to remove label and add

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make a simple game where you tap and you earn money. I made some code which does that however I don't know how to remove the label. Right now all it does is add 1 to the money variable and make new label.

.py

```
money = 0

    class GameScreen(Screen):
        def money(self):
            global money
            money += 1
            self.add_widget(Label(text=str(money), color=(1,0,0,1), font_size=(45),size_hint=(0.2,0.1), pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.9}))
            print(money)
```

.kv

```
<GameScreen>:
    name: "GameScreen"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Button:
        size: self.texture_size
        on_release: root.money()
        text: "Press"
        font_size: 50
        color: 1,1,1,1
        background_color: (0,0,0,1)
        background_normal: ""
        background_down: ""
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.6}
        width: self.texture_size[0] + dp(10)
        height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing a Label to place a widget with another text consumes recourses in an unavoidable way, you only have to update the text. So you must add the label the first time and then update the text. On the other hand it is recommended that the name of variables, classes and functions are not the same. And try to avoid using global variables because they are difficult to debug.

Making those changes we obtain the following code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        Screen.__init__(self, **args)
        self.money = 0
        self.label = Label(text=str(self.money), color=(1,0,0,1), font_size=(45),size_hint=(0.2,0.1), pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.9})
        self.add_widget(self.label)

    def add_money(self):
        self.money += 1
        self.label.text = str(self.money)

Builder.load_string('''
<GameScreen>:
    name: "GameScreen"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Button:
        size: self.texture_size
        on_release: root.add_money()
        text: "Press"
        font_size: 50
        color: 1,1,1,1
        background_color: (0,0,0,1)
        background_normal: ""
        background_down: ""
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.6}
        width: self.texture_size[0] + dp(10)
        height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(10)
    ''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GameScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: @AdamKamil 
I see that it was necessary, I just deleted the Clock.